# Yii2 add conditions to AssetBundle

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want create this result:

```
<!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I have this AppAsset Bundle

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web/frontend/assets';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css', 
    ];
    public $js = [
        'functions.js',
        'jquery.placeholder.min.js',
        'line-chart.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

I want that only jquery.placeholder.min.js have these jsOption, I tried adding jsOptions propertie without success.

```
    public $jsOptions = [
       ['condition' => 'IE 9']
    ];
```

There are a way to get this working? Or maybe I have to create a new Bundle only for these file?

I dont see more info about this in the official doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: You've got too many brackets; try `public $jsOptions = [
       'condition' => 'IE 9'
    ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your js from base bundle

```
    public $js = [
    'functions.js',
    //'jquery.placeholder.min.js',
    'line-chart.js',
 ]
```

Add a bundle in your depends

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yourapp\assets\myAsset',    
];
```

create your asset

```
<?php
 namespace yourapp\assets;

 use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class myAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $js = [
       'jquery.placeholder.min.js',
    ];

    public $jsOptions = ['condition' => 'IE 9'];
}
```